# Escaping characters issue in running Powershell script in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, escaping

I am having trouble with escaping characters in C# to run Powershell scripts. In order to make the issue short. I did the following test.

I can run the following command successfully in Powershell ISE.

```
New-Issue -Summary "Test Summary" -Description "test `"test`" "
```

Basically, the script insert a record into a database table. The table has two columns: summary and description. The value for summary is "Test Summary" and the value for description is " test "test" ".

I was trying to run the same Powershell command in C# by doing the following thing.

```
try{
    command = "New-Issue -Summary \"Test Summary \" -Description \"test `\"test`\" \"";
    powerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create();
    powerShellInstance.AddScript(command);
    Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = powerShellInstance.Invoke();
    ...
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    return e.Message;
}
```

I got error in C#. The error cannot be caught by the try catch statement. But I can see the exceptions kept thrown in output in VisualStudio, the code will hang there forever:

Exception thrown: 'System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException' in System.Management.Automation.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Management.Automation.ValidationMetadataException' in Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingValidationException' in System.Management.Automation.dll

If the description does not contain double quotes. Such as

```
 command = "New-Issue -Summary \"Test Summary \" -Description \"test \"";
```

The script runs fine in C#.
I believe I am escaping the double quotes correctly here. Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Please be noted this example is just for demonstrating purpose. I know I can insert data into table in C# in an easy way. I just want to figure out how should I run Powershell scripts in C# correctly.

Thank you.

P.S: I forgot to mention that I prefer using ` to escape the double quotes to using single quote in the description fields. Because the value for description is getting from a textbox. By doing so, i can only handle double quotes from the textbox and leave everything as it is.